# Can Featuretools perform an aggregation based on a value in another column?

Tags: python, featuretools

I have a time series dataset which includes the field day of week (DOW). I would like to use `featuretools` to perform a mean aggregation only where the day of the week equals the day of the week of the of that particular row.

For example, if I am calculating a feature matrix over a period of 2 weeks and the first row has a DOW of Monday, I need the mean between the first row and the only other row in the period which is also a Monday.

I could do this using `where_primitives`, however this would require calculating the mean for every single DOW and then perform some filtering logic afterwards to create a new field.

Thanks for the help!